# Why are my media queries being ignored?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I've used a css validator which at first was bringing up some errors to do with the media query, I have since fixed these errors (and checked again with a validator - this time bringing back 0 errors) but it is still not recognising the code in my browser. I'm using chrome.

```
/* MEDIA QUERIES ======================================================= MEDIA QUERIES */


@media screen and (max-width: 640px)  {

/* HEADER SLIDER */

#home-header .home-slider {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

#home-header .metaslider {
max-width: 90%;
margin: auto;
}



/* USE IT  ============================ USE IT */

    .circle {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto 30px;
}


#circle-3 {
    margin-right: auto;
}

#use .logo {
    display: none;
}

#use .buy-now {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

}
```

Comment: Please post the source code, outherwise it's pretty impossible for us to help you.

Comment: The HTML source is missing. please provide that so we can understand what the CSS that is provided is trying to manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

You should also make sure if your main css file has got lower priority than your media queries. Maybe #home-header styles from media queries are just being ignored?

If yes, just prepend selectors with e.g. `body div` so they will look like `body div#home-header .home-slider`. Making your selectors more precise will give them higher priority.